# How do I make RecyclerView grid "full height"?

Tags: android, gridview, grid, height, android-recyclerview

Before RecyclerView, I used this class to make grid's height dependant on it's childs(so it works fine in scrollview):

```
public class FullHeightGridView extends GridView
{
    public FullHeightGridView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public FullHeightGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public FullHeightGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                              int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
        // View.MEASURED_SIZE_MASK represents the largest height possible.
        int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MEASURED_SIZE_MASK,
                MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
    }
}
```

How can I modify GridLayoutManager to behave in the same way?

Comment: set your height to the recyclerview instead and see how

Comment: @Spentas what do you mean?

Comment: create a custom recyclerview and override the onMeasure based on ur spec

Comment: @Spentas I tried it, it doesn't work, it acts the same as the normal `RecyclerView`. We should probably be modifying `GridLayoutManager`